# Any better automation approach for us, if we need to have hot fixing right after our code merging done?

Tags: svn, merge, configuration-management

I need your suggestions on below situation:

1. We are using SVN with main trunk and several branches for Testing/PRD.
2. We will creating new branch for a batch of release, which will be merged with main trunk always.
3. We need to follow customer coding standard, so we are NOT able to make the code always incremental, but some delete of code will be happened.

Now the situation is every time, we will do the enhancement/fixing in the releasing branch for all the "approved" features, every round about impacting 2000+ files, with 5000 check-ins. We need to finally merge these code with the main trunk, then conducting code review, then build and test.

However, during above procedures, especially after we have done above. There would be some changes on CIs, selective features, and/or new "Hot" features. It means what we done has been wasted, and we have to start from another trunk to do the same.

Finally we will be failed to deliver timely, and team morale will be affected, so defects happened during the manual code merge.

I need experts to help us, how to have a better approach to deal with above situations? Or, any good practices can we have to make the auto code merge to reduce the defects?

Answer (score 0):

What your team is seem to lack is *Methodology*.

Per your description, consider **[Scrum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_%28development%29)** for your development process and releases.

[Here's a post](http://wiki.colar.net/software_releases_-_scrum_and_subversion_branches) that has a nice overview about Scrum and SVN.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with KMoraz. You should have a well defined methodology.

To add to this, I think you should look into continuous integration and nightly builds. Use tools like Jenkins to build your code as often as possible (locally).

The sooner the problem is found, the cheaper it is to fix it.

2000 files with 5000 check-ins seems a very big gap between builds.

As a configuration manager, I can tell you the effort put into a proper CI methodology and tool saved the R&D a LOT of time and money.

Good luck!